# SpringBoot - Angular 5 - CSRF

Tags: spring-boot, csrf, csrf-protection, angular5

Iam lost now and need some help.

I have a

- SpringBoot Server with SpringSecurtiy 4.3.
- Angular 5 App

And want to enable CSRF protection since it should be enabled on both by default (says the docs)
:Its NOT!

On SpringBoot I need to add these security configs:

```
http
.csrf()
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

On Angular I need to add these Modules:

```
imports: [
    ...,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule, //(!)
...
```

Bottom line the server send the XRSF-TOKEN in each response.

-But a diffrent on each one. Is that correct? I expected to be the same on a client session.

-Main problem here is that Angular5 still didnt use the XRSF-TOKEN in its post calls (e.g.). It dont set a X-XSRF-TOKEN in its requests.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Another solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040922/angular4-httpclient-csrf-does-not-send-x-xsrf-token).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and I think it is a regression due to version 5 of angular.

Until this is fixed you can add your own 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' header as I did.

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
    }
```

then extract manually a token

```
const token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
```

and add it to the header

```
this.http.post<any>(url, body, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token)})
```

Houssem

Comment: Thanks, that realy helps. :) No need to deactivate it anymore.

Comment: @H.abidi I am trying your code but getting null in const token . I am using Angular 6..Any other solution for same?