# Spring Security not creating CSRF token

Tags: java, angular, spring-security, csrf

I wish to use Spring Security (version 5.1.2) to generate a CSRF token for my Angular 7 application.  I have the following in my SecurityConfig file:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}
```

with the following RequestMapping in my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authentication")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @GetMapping("/csrf")
    public void getCsrfToken(){...}

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public RegisterOutputDTO register(@RequestBody UserDTO input){...}
}
```

I gathered from various sources that the `csrfTokenRepository` would automatically generate a cookie with header `XSRF-token` on my first `GET` call (which is what `/authentication/csrf` is for), but I am not getting a cookie back from the server.  Hence on my next `POST` call I am getting a 403 response.  What could I possibly be missing?

[image: This is my output]

Comment: It will only create cookie `XSRF-TOKEN` if it is missing. Look at the Request Headers to see if it is already present.

Comment: @Andreas I've thought of this as well, but I don't send any such token in the headers.  I can see in the application tab of Chrome that the cookie does not exist.

Comment: I believe I may have found the answer.  It appears that it is not possible to send a cookie cross-domain.  My angular application is hosted on localhost:3000 and my Java backend is hosted on localhost:9080.  It seems my options are to either deploy them on the same domain somehow or use a proxy.  Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002670/angular-5-unable-to-get-xsrf-token-from-httpxsrftokenextractor

Answer (score 1):

As indicated on the comments to my question, I found the answer to my problem. **A cookie can not be sent cross-domain.**

My frontend was deployed on `localhost:3000` and my backend on `localhost:9080`, which are considered different domains apparently.  If I go to `localhost:9080` (I get a white page, but that doesn't matter) and I then go to the application tab in Chrome, I find that the XSRF cookie I was looking for is stored like I was expecting all along. The cookie was available from the `GET` call I executed from my front-end. The problem is that the cookie needs to be available for `localhost:3000` so that Angular can make use of the cookie.

There are multiple ways you can solve this issue in your local environment.

## Use a proxy

You can use a proxy to map certain url paths to your backend. This is the solution I went with.

I run my Angular application with a webpack dev server. Webpack provides an easy way to proxy certain urls to your backend. For example:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
        '/api': 'http://localhost:9080'
    }
}
```

The Angular application runs on `localhost:3000`. Any calls to `localhost:3000/api/*`. will be forwarded to `localhost:9080/api/*`. So in my case I no longer perform a `GET` call on `localhost:9080/api/authentication/csrf`, but I call `localhost:3000/api/authentication/csrf` which will then get forwarded to my backend. (I added `/api` to the path in my rest controller, for those wondering.)

## Deploy both applications on the same port

Using the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) you can build the frontend to its dist folder and then let maven package the dist folder along with the backend for deploy. I haven't tried this, but there are various resources that show this should be easy to do with Spring boot. So both frontend and backend would be available through `localhost:9080` for example.

## Use Spring Profile to disable csrf locally

You can make use of Spring `@Profile` annotations to create a different configuration for local environment and the rest (test, acceptance, production). Csrf can simply be disabled for development. I do not prefer this option since I like to keep DEV and other environments the same as much as possible. It's also not a real answer to the problem statement.

[Special thanks to the answer of user @dspies which helped me find the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002670/angular-5-unable-to-get-xsrf-token-from-httpxsrftokenextractor)

Comment: I have a very similar setup in my local too, but Spring is sending the XSRF token, and Angular is sending it back to Spring just fine. I am very confused with this answer.