# Handling CORS and CSRF between Spring Boot and Angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot back-end application that runs on port 8888 and an Angular front-end app that runs on 4200.

In my Spring Boot application i've defined the following bean to handle CORS:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

And my `HttpSecurity` configuration looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        // ... the rest of the config
}
```

With this configuration everything works fine, i can successfully call my API from the Angular app.

But i would like to enable CSRF, so i've changed the security config to the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        // ... the rest of the config
}
```

And i've added the following `HttpInterceptor` to my Angular app:

```
constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
    if (token) {
        req = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token } });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

The problem is `tokenExtractor.getToken()` always returns `null`.

The corresponding request and response headers look like this:

[image]

The `XSRF-TOKEN` response cookie is present.

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I've tried importing the `HttpClientXsrfModule` in my Angular app, but it doesn't make any difference.

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002670/angular-5-unable-to-get-xsrf-token-from-httpxsrftokenextractor

Answer (score 0):

No need. You can use chrome nosecurity or install Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin is ok to resolve the problem.

Comment: I think it's bad advice to circumvent security things; and how should this work with other users of the application?

Comment: we use the method in dev environment. we can't meet cross domain in AT or production environment.

Comment: but that's not the environment that the question addresses. So while your answer may be enough for your setup, it probalby does not answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code in my Spring Boot apps and it works great with Angular

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

as said in the documentation [ ...you can enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) from either in individual controllers or globally...]

- Controller Method CORS Configuration: can be enabled using @CrossOrigin annotation
- Global CORS configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer(){
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){

                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*").maxAge(3600);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact Spring handles the server side implementation here. All you have to do is add the `.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())` config, as you did.

The security pattern that Spring implements for you here, is the "cookie-to-header" pattern. Spring adds a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` to the response of your GET request. Let's say the value is `aa5f7a64-cf4d-4706-b5aa-bcdec2b41798`.

When you try to do a POST request, Spring will return a `403 Forbidden`, unless you add a header with key `X-XSRF-TOKEN` and the value of the cookie you got from the GET request. For our example, that would be `aa5f7a64-cf4d-4706-b5aa-bcdec2b41798`.

Spring will check whether the value of the cookie and of the header are the same. Only if they are the same, the request will pass. Otherwise you get a `403 Forbidden`.