# How to set XSRF-TOKEN in Angular 11 API request header in Laravel 8?

Tags: angular, laravel, api, csrf-token, x-xsrf-token

I integrate `Angular (11) frontend` within the `Laravel 8` application. For making API requests, users are logged in. Every time the frontend Angular makes a request to the backend API, I get the following error:

```
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

I have set up `VueJs frontend` to test the same API endpoint URL and VueJs can reach the API endpoint and get response back from the backend as well. When I compare the `Request Headers` of the API request making by VueJS with the request making by Angular 11, I see that the `Request Headers` of `Angular 11` does not have `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. So I think that is the reason why I get the above error.

Below is how `VueJs` and `AXIOS` are setup within Laravel 8 to have the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in the `API Request Headers`.

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = token.content;
}
```

How to set the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` or `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the `API Request Headers` making by `Angular 11` within `Laravel 8`?

Note: Angular 11 frontend and VueJs frontend are both integrated on the frontend web page of the Laravel 8 application, thus they are on the same domain. So I think `laravel-cors` package is not needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular4 httpclient csrf does not send x-xsrf-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040922/angular4-httpclient-csrf-does-not-send-x-xsrf-token)

Comment: I don't know where to find the value for `headerName` . HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
   headerName: 'What should it be here??'
 })

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the XSRF token, you has to use a non-modifying HTTP method containing header X-CSRF-Token with the value Fetch . The token is issued only if the user has already been authenticated. If the user has not been authenticated , any request with a modifying method is rejected by this filter. For more info about XSRF protection Click [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/79/108d3aacaf4209b91b760280f82e13/content.htm)!

Comment: Sending  XSRF token : 1.You can create a new route to show the csrf token using your controller with help of the function below. ( ...
2.Select the Body tab on postman and then choose x-www-form-urlencoded.
3.Copy the token and paste in postman as the value of the key named _token.
4.Execute your post request on your URL/Endpoint.

Comment: I cannot follow you, why do you talk about using postman. I already have a working API end point, no need to use Postman to test the API url end point. What I want to know is how to set X-XSRF-TOKEN in the API Request Headers in Angular 4, 5, 9 or 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
imports: [ HttpClientModule,HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header'})]; // headerName is optional
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it