# CSRF using absolute URL - Angular

Tags: angular, csrf

I am looking to deploy an angular frontend app on gh-pages and deploy a springboot app on heroku so they will obviously be running on different servers. Default angular xsrf doesn't seem to be able to support this. Is there a clean way to auto handle all of the csrf cookies and headers or do I need to hack together a solution such as here? [angular4 httpclient csrf does not send x-xsrf-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040922/angular4-httpclient-csrf-does-not-send-x-xsrf-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `HttpInterceptor` and make sure to include it in the app.module as a provider.

Here is an example of a a similar class I use. You can replace the conditions in the `If` Condition to match your specific use cases.

You can find out more about HTTP Interceptors in Angular [Here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AbsoluteurlCsrfHeaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor,
    private environment: Environment
  ) {}

  // add application default headers to all requests
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = 'X-CSRF-Token';

    const token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    let newReq = req.clone();

    // because we are using aboslute paths in development mode
    // we can't rely on the built in CSRF behavior
    // if we are not in prod mode and the url is absolute (begins with http)
    // add the csrf token if one exists
    if ( !this.environment.production
      && this.environment.api_endpoint.length
      && ( req.url.substr(0, 4 ) === 'http' || req.url.substr(0, 5 ) === 'https')
      && token !== null
      && !req.headers.get(headerName)
    ) {
      newReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token)});
    }

    return next.handle(newReq);
  }

}
```

Comment: Not seeing it in the docs but I assume HttpXsrfTokenExtractor automatically keeps track of the latest CSRF-Token and isn't something I need to be worried about?

Comment: as long as you are using the same interceptors throughout your app, i.e. defined in the AppModule, then you should be fine.

Comment: Does it even make sense to have csrf token if I am going to allow other sites to be able to see and use it (setting sameSite=None and Secure)? Seems like just the nature of the cross-site talking between gh-pages and heroku makes any crsf security a moot point.